# Android kSOAP: Invoke WebService on SAP for complex parameter

Tags: android, sap-erp, ksoap

I am trying to invoke a web service on a SAP system and am having a problem trying to pass a complex parameter in.

The web service has 3 input parameters. 2 Strings and a complex parameter which references a SAP structure which contains several fields. These 3 input parameters are called:

- `Function`
- `Parameters`
- `Repid`

`Funtion` and `Repid` are passed in ok when I invoke the web service, however, nothing is passed into the input parameter named `Parameters`.

I have the following code to set up the complex parameter input: -

```
    final ReportExecutionParametersDefinition exeParams = new ReportExecutionParametersDefinition();

    exeParams.setSelname("P_AUART");
    exeParams.setKind("P");
    exeParams.setSign("I");
    exeParams.setOption("EQ");
    exeParams.setLow("ZA");
    exeParams.setHigh(" ");

    final PropertyInfo pinfo = new PropertyInfo();

    pinfo.name = "Parameters";
    pinfo.setValue(exeParams);
    pinfo.type = exeParams.getClass();
```

The following code is used to invoke the web service: -

```
            KSOAPFactory soapFact = new KSOAPFactory();

            soapFact.initialiseSOAPEnvelope(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME, URL);

            soapFact.addProperty("Function", "EXE");
            soapFact.addProperty(pinfo);
            soapFact.addProperty("Repid", reportDef.getReportHeader()
                    .getReport());

            try {
                resp = soapFact.invokeSOAP();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I look in SAP, no values are passed in the for `Parameters` input parameter.

Has anyone every used kSOAP to invoke a SAP web service to populate a complex input parameter?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Solved it for myself. I never realised I needed to populate the overide methods getProperty, getPropertyCount and getPropertyInfo

Hope this helps someone else who has similar issues.